# Xamarin- How to make expand the listview programmatically?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am using the xamarin form to code the project, however now i encounter an issue which is, when i using the listview and deploy to the android, the android showed the hamburger icon which the IOS does not exist. I am intend to create this icon in the IOS so the IOS user will know there is a listview. However when i find the listview function, there is no any function to expand or close the listview. How do i expand the listview programmatically?

```
<ListView 
  x:Name="campaignList" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Campaigns}" 
  ItemTapped="OnItemSelected">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <TextCell 
          Text="{Binding Name}" 
          Detail="{Binding Description}" TextColor="#000"
          DetailColor="#999"/> 
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Do you mean Navigation Menu (Fly Over menu) ? If so are you using MasterDetailPage ?

Comment: i duno what is fly over menu, however the code is
<ListView x:Name="campaignList" ItemsSource="{Binding Campaigns}" ItemTapped="OnItemSelected" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Description}" TextColor="#000" DetailColor="#999"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>

and i am using master detail page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean Opening the `Master` Page (which contains `ListView`) of `MasterDetail` Page, by exapnding the ListView (NB: If so, please edit the question accordingly so that it will be of use for others in future)

```
public class MyPage : MasterDetailPage
{
   void ToggleMasterPage(bool openMenu)
   {
       IsPresented = openPage;
   }
}
```

You can invoke ToggleMasterPage method by passing `True` to open the `Master` page programmatically  and `False` to close .